# Angular, <template> element and #document-fragment

Tags: angular-template

1. If I add `<template><img src="url1" /></template>` in any basic HTML page, the img resource at `url1` is not downloaded, and according to Chrome DevTools a document-fragment containing the img element is created

[image]

2. If I add `<template><img src="url2" /></template>` to any Angular component template file, the img resource at `url2` is downloaded, and the DOM contains a template element with an empty document-fragment and a img element as siblings

[image]

How can I add the `<template ...` snippet to a Angular template as in 2), but have the same result as in 1)?

ngNonBindable on the `<template>` element or the `<img>` element seems to have no effect.
I am using Angular 10.
I need to do this because I am using a 3rd party library which needs to be configured using a `<template>` element with specific token as `img` `src` value which will be replaced internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<template>` HTML tags are definitely rendered differently in Angular.

Use the `[innerHTML]` binding to get your template to render the content like it does outside of Angular. When testing your example, I needed to define the `img` HTML as a separate variable in the component as follows so as to not be sanitized by Angular:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  htmlStr: string = '<img src="url1" />';
}
```

source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-innerhtml-binding-angular

Now use the `htmlStr` variable in the `<template>` with `[innerHTML]`:

```
<template [innerHTML]="htmlStr"> </template>
```

These were additional sources for my answer: [Angular 6 create HTMLElement from HTMLTemplateElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925660/angular-6-create-htmlelement-from-htmltemplateelement)
https://dev.to/patricksevat/using-web-components-custom-elements-in-template-tag-htmltemplateelement-using-angular-1ik8

Comment: Thank you Allen, that solves my issue. Do you have any reference as to why Angular behaves this way with this tag?

Comment: Pierre, that’s a great follow up question that I don’t know the mechanics well enough to answer. Much of the difficulty in researching this is that most search engine results point you to templates for angular instead of the html template element being used in angular. If you ever come across the exact reason please share.

Comment: No definitive answer, but you can see a couple comments on the dev.to post Allen.